# VMware Workstation 17 Player - processor cores assignment

Tags: virtual-machine

I've started to use VMware Workstation 17 Player and I need clarification on assignment of processor cores; if I choose to assign x number of cores, does VMware share those cores with host machine or are those cores unavailable to host while virtual machine runs.

In case virtual machine shares cores with host, is it ok do assign all cores to virtual machine?

I couldn't find answer regarding this on VMware docs and on stack community they closed this question because it's not about programming or software development.

Comment: This doesn't really class as a software recommendation, but a technical issue - it would be abetter fit for https://superuser.com I'm sure there are already duplicates on there already. Your 'ideal' for performance on a single VM [assuming you have HT] is assign the same number of cores as you have physical cores. HT will do the rest for you.

Comment: Thank for answer, I've found similar answers on superuser group.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. If you intended to ask for software, please see  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Otherwise please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits. You could start with [SuperUser](//superuser.com/help/on-topic), for example – which you already found I see.